# Summernote get mentions from php with many value

Tags: summernote, mention

I added SummerNote Editor into my Website and i try to make Mention And i have a problem:

It works fine if left like this:
`

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
            $("#content").summernote({
                dialogsInBody: true,
                height: 150,
                toolbar: [
                    ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                    ['color', ['color']],
                    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                    ['table', ['table']],
                    ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video', 'hr']]
                  ],
                  hint: {
                  mentions: [{"userid":"25","name":"Checkbnotif","dir":"201910","avatar":"","slug":"checkbnotif"}],
                        match: /\B@(\w*)$/,
                        search: function (keyword, callback) {
                            callback($.grep(this.mentions, function (item) {
                                return item.slug.indexOf(keyword) == 0;
                            }));
                        },
                        template: function (item) {
                            return '<img src="'+ baseURL + 'assets/userstore/'+ item.dir +'/'+  item.avatar + '" width="20" />' + item.name + '';
                        },
                        content: function (item) {
                            return $('<span><b><span class="href" data-id="'+item.usserid+'">@' + item.name + '</span>&nbsp;</b></span>')[0];
                        }
                    }
            });
});
```

`

But when i use phpfile for mention then it not working:
`

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
            $("#content").summernote({
                dialogsInBody: true,
                height: 150,
                toolbar: [
                    ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                    ['color', ['color']],
                    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                    ['table', ['table']],
                    ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video', 'hr']]
                  ],
                  hint: {

                        match: /\B@(\w*)$/,
                        mentions: function(keyword, callback) {
                             $.ajax({
                                 url: baseURL + "thanh_vien/userjson/" + keyword,
                                 type: 'get',
                                 dataType: "json",   
                                 async: false
                             }).done(callback);
                         },

                        search: function (keyword, callback) {
                            callback($.grep(this.mentions, function (item) {
                                return item.slug.indexOf(keyword) == 0;
                            }));
                        },
                        template: function (item) {
                            return '<img src="'+ baseURL + 'assets/userstore/'+ item.dir +'/'+  item.avatar + '" width="20" />' + item.name + '';
                        },
                        content: function (item) {
                            return $('<span><b><span class="href" data-id="'+item.usserid+'">@' + item.name + '</span>&nbsp;</b></span>')[0];
                        }
                    }
            });
});
`
```

My php file is json data look like:

```
[{"userid":"25","name":"Checkbnotif","dir":"201910","avatar":"","slug":"checkbnotif"}]
```

Please show me how it work ! I'm a newbie and i try to do something ! 
Sorry my English

Answer (score 0):

`metions` is sample data.

So `this.mentions` in search function will be not work.

you can redefine search function .

```
search: function (keyword, callback) {

    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL + "thanh_vien/userjson/" + keyword,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: "json",   
        async: false
    }).done(function (items) {
        callback($.grep(items, function (item) {
            return item.slug.indexOf(keyword) == 0;
        }));
    });

},
```

Comment: Thank Jinho ! It work perfect but I need one more help, I want when the user types at least 2 characters after @ to search for the member to mention ! can u show me ! Thank you